# Invalid Column Name During SQL Data Read

Tags: sql, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I'm working on a project in which I need to search for an employee's name in a database and then display their information in a listBox. The issue I'm having is that whenever I attempt to search for it using a name it always gives me the "invalid column name" error. Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
 //If only value for First Name is given
        if (EmpID.Text == "" && FirstName.Text != "" && LName.Text == "" && SuperID.Text == "")
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlDBConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Fname = " + FirstName.Text;
            SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader2.Read())
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add((reader2[0].ToString() + "\t\t" + reader2[1].ToString() + "\t\t" + reader2[2].ToString()
                    + "\t\t" + reader2[3].ToString() + "\t\t" + reader2[4].ToString() + "\t\t" + reader2[5].ToString()));
            }
            reader2.Close();
        }
```

Comment: can u provide your database Employee table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Fname = '" + FirstName.Text+"'";
```

Comment: Thanks! I had actually managed to find some "in-person" help with it as well.